# Как сверстать элементы списка с кнопкой рядом?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, dom

Собственно пишу свой ToDoList, используя только JS.
Не могу понять как сверстать элемент списка с кнопкой справа как показано на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что если назначить display:inline-block для моей li кнопка станет там где-нужно, но другие li моего списка уже будет не в столбик а строку..

Comment: li - это блок, в котором можно поместить 2 других блока. <li><span>Сходить к врачу<span><input type="button"></li>

Comment: Оберните этот li в один div и задайте ширину. А лучше всего поправьте и покажите свой html
А еще лучше сделайте просто центрируйте все это и сделайте содержимое li inline

Comment: Выглядит приятно, спасибо. Но когда создаешь это с помощью js, то выглядит ресурсозатратно, больше нет альтернатив?

Comment: Это нормальная практика, ничего ресурсозатратного в этом нет. Вам нужно написать 2 функции. 1. Создает элемент списка. 2. Создает список - перебирает исходный массив данных и создает элементы списка, используя ф-ю из п. 1. (либо все объедините в 1 функцию, кому как удобней)

Comment: Все понял, спасибо огромное

Comment: Опять же, не забывайте, когда вы работаете со строчными элементами inline-block, то они будут идти по порядку в строке, иными словами, если у вас будет длинная строка, то кнопка перенесется на новую строку и будет находится в ее конце. Используйте grid/flex/float для позиционирования.